# Как вывести сообщение о том, что список ничего не нашел?

Tags: java, map, treemap

У меня есть список, в виде словаря.

```java
TreeMap<Product, Integer> listTree = new TreeMap;
```

`Product` - принимает `String name` и `int age`; `new SortProductByCost` - `Comparator`, который сортирует возраст.

Мне нужно создать метод, который удаляет определенный элемент по имени, но метод принимает как параметр `String name`, при этом, если список ничего не найдет, то вывести сообщение, что товар не найден.

Мой пример:

```java
public void deleteProduct(String name) {
    try {
        for (Map.Entry<Product, Integer> entry : listProductMap.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().getName().equals(name)) {
                listProductMap.remove(entry.getKey());
                System.out.println("Удален");
                return;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: После цикла вставьте ваше сообщение

Comment: @Serodv, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

У вас может быть *несколько* ключей `Product`, удовлетворяющих условию равенства поля `name`, поэтому достаточно использовать метод [`Collection::removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) для набора ключей, который возвращает `true`, если хотя бы один ключ был удалён:

```java
TreeMap<Product, Integer> listProductMap = new TreeMap<>();

public void deleteProductsByName(String name) {
    if (listProductMap.keySet().removeIf(pKey -> name.equals(pKey.getName())) {
        System.out.println("Ключи удалены");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Товары не найдены");
    }
}
```

---

Аналогично, можно отфильтровать ключи по заданному признаку/признакам, а затем удалить их, используя стандартный метод [`Collection::removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-), который также возвращает `true`, если сет ключей изменился после удаления.
В таком случае удобнее выполнить дополнительные операции над множеством ключей, удаляемых из мапы:

```java
public void deleteProductsByName(String name) {
    Set<Product> prodsToDelete = listProductMap.keySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(productKey -> name.equals(productKey.getName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    if (listProductMap.keySet().removeAll(prodsToDelete)) {
        System.out.println("Удалённые ключи: " + prodsToDelete);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Товары не найдены");
    }
}
```

---

Если же нужно удалить *только первый* ключ, удовлетворяющий условию, как показано в коде, приведённом в вопросе, то достаточно вывести соответствующее сообщение после цикла, как посоветовали в комментариях к вопросу:

```java
public void deleteFirstProductByName(String name) {
    for (Product key : listProductMap.keySet()) {
        if (name.equals(key.getName()) 
            && listProductMap.keySet().remove(key)) {
            System.out.println("Удалённый товар: " + key);
            return; // избегаем ConcurrentModificationException
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Товар не найден: " + name);
}
```

Аналогично с использованием Stream API `Stream::findFirst` + [`Optional::ifPresentOrElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse(java.util.function.Consumer,java.lang.Runnable)):

```java
public void deleteFirstProductByName(String name) {
    listProductMap.keySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(key -> name.equals(key.getName())
        .findFirst() // Optional<Product>
        .ifPresentOrElse(key -> {
                listProductMap.keySet().remove(key);
                System.out.println("Удалённый товар: " + key);
            }, 
            () -> System.out.println("Товар не найден: " + name)
        );
}
```